# Python instances stored in shelves change after closing it

Tags: python, instance, pickle, shelve

I think the best way to explain the situation is with an example:

```
>>> class Person:
...     def __init__(self, brother=None):
...         self.brother = brother
... 
>>> bob = Person()
>>> alice = Person(brother=bob)
>>> import shelve
>>> db = shelve.open('main.db', writeback=True)
>>> db['bob'] = bob
>>> db['alice'] = alice
>>> db['bob'] is db['alice'].brother
True
>>> db['bob'] == db['alice'].brother
True
>>> db.close()
>>> db = shelve.open('main.db',writeback=True)
>>> db['bob'] is db['alice'].brother
False
>>> db['bob'] == db['alice'].brother
False
```

The expected output for both comparisons is `True` again. However, `pickle` (which is used by `shelve`) seems to be re-instantiating `bob` and `alice.brother` separately. How can I "fix" this using `shelve`/`pickle`? Is it possible for `db['alice'].brother` to point to `db['bob']` or something similar? Notice I do not want only to compare both, I need both to actually be the same.

As suggested by **Blckknght** I tried pickling the entire dictionary at once, but the problem persists since it seems to pickle each key separately.

Comment: @user2357112 Just an example class, shouldn't make a difference... See http://pastebin.com/hCxSU54n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the issue you're seeing comes from the way the `shelve` module stores its values. Each value is pickled independently of the other values in the shelf, which means that if the same object is inserted as a value under multiple keys, the identity will not be preserved between the keys. However, if a single value has multiple references to the same object, the identity will be maintained within that single value.

Here's an example:

```
a = object() # an arbitrary object
db = shelve.open("text.db")
db['a'] = a
db['another_a'] = a
db['two_a_references'] = [a, a]
db.close()

db = shelve.open("text.db") # reopen the db
print(db['a'] is db['another_a']) # prints False
print(db['two_a_references'][0] is db['two_a_references'][1]) # prints True
```

The first print tries to confirm the identity of two versions of the object `a` that were inserted in the database, one under the key `'a'` directly, and another under `'another_a'`. It doesn't work because the separate values are pickled separately, and so the identity between them was lost.

The second print tests whether the two references to `a` that were stored under the key `'two_a_references'` were maintained. Because the list was pickled in one go, the identity is kept.

So to address your issue you have a few options. One approach is to avoid testing for identity and rely on an `__eq__` method in your various object types to determine if two objects are semantically equal, even if they are not the same object. Another would be to bundle all your data into a single object (e.g. a dictionary) which you'd then save with `pickle.dump` and restore with `pickle.load` rather than using `shelve` (or you could adapt [this recipe for a persistent dictionary](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576642/), which is linked from the `shelve` docs, and does pretty much that).

Comment: Exactly! Thing is, I am already bundling all my data on a big dictionary, but as you mentioned the identity is not kept because each key is pickled separately anyway. I'll try to mess with `shelve` options and use just `pickle` but I doubt it'll help, since `shelve` is [just a class that makes pickling easier](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shelve.py).

Comment: Only using the [persistent dictionary recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576642/) AND bundling everything in a big dict solved the problem. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way, in Python, is to implement the `__eq__` and `__ne__` functions inside of the Person class, like this:

```
class Person(object):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (isinstance(other, self.__class__)
            and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
```

Generally, that should be sufficient, but if these are truly database objects and have a primary key, it would be more efficient to check that attribute instead of `self.__dict__`.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

To preserve identity with `shelve` you need to preserve identity with `pickle`[read this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

**Solution**

This class saves all the objects on its class site and restores them if the identity is the same. You should be able to subclass from it.

```
>>> class PickleWithIdentity(object):
    identity = None
    identities = dict() # maybe use weakreference dict here
    def __reduce__(self):
        if self.identity is None:
            self.identity = os.urandom(10) # do not use id() because it is only 4 bytes and not random
            self.identities[self.identity] = self
        return open_with_identity, (self.__class__, self.__dict__), self.__dict__


>>> def open_with_identity(cls, dict):
    if dict['identity'] in cls.identities:
        return cls.identities[dict['identity']]
    return cls()

>>> p = PickleWithIdentity()
>>> p.asd = 'asd'
>>> import pickle
>>> import os
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(p))
<__main__.PickleWithIdentity object at 0x02D2E870>
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(p)) is p
True
```

**Further problems** can occur because the state may be overwritten:

```
>>> p.asd
'asd'
>>> ps = pickle.dumps(p)
>>> p.asd = 123
>>> pickle.loads(ps)
<__main__.PickleWithIdentity object at 0x02D2E870>
>>> p.asd
'asd'
```